# angular 11 display static text to dynamic value

Tags: angular-material, angular10

I'm having 2 JSONs. The first one is having the format of the JSON value and the second one is having the actual value which is I want to display in the UI.

But I'm seeing the "application.appID" instead of 101. Does any help please?

Not working if  label:"applicaiton.appID". I'm having label: "string"

working  if   label: applicaiton.appID

component.ts

```
 this.json1={
label:"applicaiton.appID"
};

this.application ={
appID:101
};
```

ui.html

```
<mat-label> {{json1.label}} </mat-label>
<mat-label [innterHtml]="json1.lable"> </mat-label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right, what you're trying to do is to interpolate based on a string expression coming from a json. This is not something that you can do by just using the {{ }} construct. Here's why:

*(For simplicity I will use div instead of mat-label)*

In theory, this line would solve your problem

```html
<div>{{this[json1.label]}}</div>
```

Just that it doesn't work since the inner `json1.label` part is not expanded/evaluated as expected.

Even if we manually write it as an explicit string, it still doesn't give us `101`.

```html
<div>{{this['application.appID']}}</div>
```

The only way to make such a syntax work would be to chain the field indexers, but that doesn't help us with using json1.label as the 'path' of the object and inner field.

```html
<div>{{this['application']['appID']}}</div> // this returns 101, but it's not helpful for us...
```

---

So as you can see, pure html interpolation can't really help us achieve our goal. Instead, we should create a helper method inside the .component.ts file:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

  json1 = {
    label: 'application.appID'
  };

  application = {
    appID: 101
  };

  accessPropertyByString(path: string): any {
    let result = this;
    const parts = path.split('.');
    for (const part of parts) {
      if (part in result) {
        result = result[part];
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

The new `accessPropertyByString()` method can be now used in the html template like this:

```html
<div>{{accessPropertyByString(json1.label)}}</div>
```

Which finally returns `101` as expected.